# Neo4j Embedded Java API Perfomance

Tags: java, neo4j

The question is regarding the

> findNode(label, propertyName, propertyValue)

function. Once I have the node, what operations are cheap and what operations are expensive ? For example, does the node object get retrieved together with all its properties or does each

> node.getProperty

call incur additional performance cost ?
Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findNode(label, propertyName, propertyValue)` uses an index to retrieve the matching nodes. The properties won't be loaded with the resulting nodes.

`node.getProperty` will cause the entire property chain to be loaded (i.e. all the node's properties). So the first call to this method on any node/relationship is relatively "expensive", the subsequent ones will be cheap.